# Inductive sets in ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

In a real analysis book, I read that an ordered field has at least 2 inductive sets and also can have many more. I am not able to understand how "at least 2"? Please clarify.

Comment: What is your definition of inductive set?

Comment: Inductive set (I) is the subset of F such that (a) 1 belongs to I  (b) for x belongs to F, x belongs to I implies x+1 also belongs to I